# Does a VBA module in Excel treated as a spreadsheet in NPOI or POI?

Tags: npoi

I am working on a `NPOI` project.

I have an `Excel` file which contains `5` spread sheets out of which:

- `2` are hidden (as they are dialog, user interface, kind of sheets `DlgView1`, `DlgView2`).
- `3` work sheets (`WrkSht1, WrkSht2, WrkSht3`) are visible with some data containing formulas and external links.

Also, the `Excel` sheet contains a `VBA module` called `Module1.bas` with some logic.

When I check the number of worksheets using `workbook.NumberOfSheets` property, it shows `5`, but when I iterate through the code for all worksheets present, I get the below results:

```
1. Sheet1 = DlgView1 -------> which is hidden 
2. Sheet2 = DlgView2 -------> which is hidden 
3. Sheet3 = Module1  -------> which is hidden --->This is what is confusing!!!! 
4. Sheet4 = WrkSht1 ------->  which is visible    
5. Sheet5 = WrkSht2 ------->  which is visible
```

It should have been like this instead I suppose:

```
1. Sheet1 = DlgView1 -------> which is hidden
2. Sheet2 = DlgView2 -------> which is hidden
3. Sheet3 = WrkSht1  -------> which is visible
4. Sheet4 = WrkSht2 ------->  which is visible
5. Sheet5 = WrkSht3 ------->  which is visible
```

I cannot get access to one of the visible worksheet `WrkSht3` as the count(= 5) of worksheet ends by this time.

Also, when my code sets to play around different cells of worksheet `WrkSht1`, it will actually be pointing to `WrkSht2` and for worksheet `WrkSht2`, it will actually be pointing to `WrkSht3`.

But `WrkSht3` was never initialzed as a worksheet as seen from the above results.

For testing purpose, I deleted `Module1` and checked, it works fine with count as `5` and considering all the worksheets (`DlgView1, DlgView2, WrkSht1, WrkSht2, WrkSht3`) to process.

Also, to mention, I get an exception thrown while working with this file & not with any others:

`Unsupported BOF found of type VBModule`

**My question is:**

Does `NPOI` or `POI` treat a `VBA module` in a `Excel` sheet as a hidden worksheet?

- If not, why is the code considering `Module1` as worksheet and not the actual visible worksheet `WrkSht3` as explained above.
- If yes, is there a way to tell code not consider `VBA Modules` as worksheets and also actual visible worksheets like `WrkSht3`.

If needed, I can send the `Excel` sheet which I am working on. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure still how better & precise could my question have been.

Comment: Just so you know, NPOI is not associated with Apache POI. the two are developed independently, and Apache POI does not use any code or processes from NPOI.

Comment: @Sneak: Thank you. Will follow the format moving forward

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: I know NPOI & Apache POI are different. I needed a solution or an answer to my question either from NPOI or Apache POI stand point. Because, I know NPOI is open source which uses the classes built from Apache POI using .Net language.